# Question about Speeding and Calculus

Tags: calculus

At 6.00 am, a driver picked up a fare card at the entrance of a tollway. At 10:30 am, the driver pulled up to a toll booth 250 miles away. After computing the fare, the toll booth operator issues a speeding ticket to the driver. (The posted speed limit was 65 mph). The driver said he was not speeding. Was he lying?

What I did to solve this problem is to find the average speed of the driver which came out to be 55 mph, using distance/time. Then by the mean value theorem, he/she apparently was not speeding.

Is there any other theorem that can be used to show that the driver was speeding?

Comment: You can't say for certain that the driver was not speeding. What you can say is that the operator can't use the mean value theorem to issue a ticket. It's conceivable that at some point, the driver sped over 65 mph but then pulled over and waited a while at a diner or something. Now, had the driver's speed averaged at 65 mph, there might be grounds for a speeding ticket; it's impossible the driver drove 65 mph from start to finish, as there must be a several seconds to accelerate up to 65 mph. Thus, if the average is *exactly* 65 mph, then at some point, he was speeding.

Comment: @daOnlyBG, is there perhaps any other theorem, that can be used? I do not have the velocity function of this driver or anything.

Answer (score 1):

Using distance over time, you have $\frac {250}{4.5} =55 \frac 59$ mph. You certainly can't prove he was speeding. Even a half hour rest stop would only give a speed when traveling of $\frac {250}4=62.5$mph. You are *far* off from proving speeding here.

Answer (score 0):

**There is no way to determine if the driver was speeding.**  Sure, they could go a constant $55$mph the whole time (and did not speed), or they could have gone $400$mph for a short time and slowed to a crawl until 10:30am.  Since either approach would fit the two data points given, we cannot determine if they actually did exceed $55$mph.

The way this problem *typically* goes, the driver's average speed exceeds the speed limit, and you can conclude they were speeding.  However, this seems to be an odd case.

Comment: Yeah that is what I am thinking. Maybe my teacher made a mistake.

Comment: @Hello I believe that is the case.  Or, they wanted you to realize that you can't determine if the driver was speeding. :)